# RTMFP live webcam streaming (one-to-many) - Questions

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, streaming, webcam, multicast

I'm planning to develop a website that allows to live webcam streams. I tested Adobe RTFMP protocol with Adobe Cirrus and it seems to work great for low amount of people, but I wonder how it will act in situation when one person streams to 300 or more. I do not use any RTMFP server (just rtmfp://p2p.rtmfp.net/MY_KEY).

And my questions:

**1. Is it possible to build Flash application that will handle many people streaming/watching streams using only Adobe Cirrus? (I mean without setting up my own server)**

**2. If yes, Does RTMFP provides any firewall/NAT traversal things? I mean that when someone will be deep behind firewall/router etc, will it connect?** 
I ask because I got strange situation with my friend. When I was streaming webcam by my app, he could watch me. When he was streaming by this same app, I couldn't watch him. It didn't even discovered him as a NetGroup.Neightbour. We are in the same network. Could it be his software problem?

**3. Should I use any open-source RTMFP server like Red5 to create this?**

If you got any other ideas how should it be implemented, please share.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I am late to answer this question, but I only found it now.

> 1. Is it possible to build Flash application that will handle many people streaming/watching streams using only Adobe Cirrus? (I mean
>      without setting up my own server)

Answer: Yes I did it before, but on the server side you need to construct a framework to handle that. In my case I used like 
 rtmfp://p2p.rtmfp.net/MY_APP?variables=xxx) to instantiate my framework and call my streaming. Also I had implemented a RESTFull call on my application webserver (another machine) to detect user rights over the content. Adobe Product will suggest the use of it's own implementation but over time you will see that it's simple implementation won't last.

> 2. If yes, Does RTMFP provides any firewall/NAT traversal things? I mean that when someone will be deep behind firewall/router etc, will
>      it connect? I ask because I got strange situation with my friend. When
>      I was streaming webcam by my app, he could watch me. When he was
>      streaming by this same app, I couldn't watch him. It didn't even
>      discovered him as a NetGroup.Neightbour. We are in the same network.
>      Could it be his software problem?

Answer: Yes it's possible for a server behind a NAT/Firewall to accept your connection and serve you the streaming however over time a fluctuation on the network may put your connection in sleep mode(were you just stop to see images) and you will need to create a strategy to keep the connection alive I also get through this in my own strategy.

> 3. Should I use any open-source RTMFP server like Red5 to create this?

Answer: I don't know, that's your personal choice, but I can tell you this. I used Flash Media Server since version 2 until version 4.5 where I never have to change my infrastructure and after that I left the job. But In that time, Our company needed Adobe support and it's answer about our problem was just like nothing. As if we were bad programmers and Adobe never wanted  look into our own code and business approach. What adobe did was to ask  get a premium support by paying a stupendous amount of money just to look into our problem to say anything about it. So I decided to write the company own framework for Server side (FMS) and that solved a problem that had almost two years. Our own framework created a nice flow between 4k users online(our max peak at that time). Before this our peak was 2k online connections watching and many freezes on the Server needing restart it manually and gradually accepting users to handshake its connection back or the server would behavior like a crazy horse (kicking everybody).

So I believe because if Red5 is free you can give a try. I know that the problem still exist in the most recent version of the FMS today but at same time the product has now three modes of operations Unicast, P2P and MultiCast. On my time, creating services on that product I used Unicast mode and P2P wasn't even ready yet. I really believe that P2P and Multicast modes was the "fix" intended for the Unicast problem I described above.

I hope this help you and others to judge your situation.